# How can I connect MySql, Oracle and Postgres databases inside docker (Mac os Mojave)?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, postgresql, rdbms

What I wish to achieve is that I should be able to query Oracle from Mysql and Mysql from Oracle. Similarly, I should be able to query for other combinations as well. I have tried searching many things but I am out of luck for this one. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks a ton!

Comment: You can connect as usual, you just have to `EXPOSE` the correct port in your dockerfile/docker-compose.

Comment: @ZachChilders can you please provide me a link to this? I am also new to docker. Thank a lott for your help.